# Django login error, LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is not working

Tags: python, django

When I click the login button the next page shows **HTTP ERROR 405**.

Register works fine, but the only login doesn't work.
Should I make login class and 'success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')'?

I think LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is the problem, but I'm not sure.
Why is this happening?

urls.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import path
from apps.common.views import HomeView, SignUpView, DashboardView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('dashboard/', DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),

path('register/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='register'),

path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
template_name = 'common/login.html'
),
name='login'),

 path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
    next_page='home'
    ),
    name='logout'
),
]
```

view.py is

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    from .forms import SignUpForm
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy

    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from django.contrib import messages

    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView  

    class HomeView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'common/home.html'

    class DashboardView(TemplateView):
       template_name = 'common/dashboard.html'
        login_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    class SignUpView(CreateView):
        form_class = SignUpForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
        template_name = 'common/register.html'
```

I also add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'` in settings.py

Comment: To what view do you send a POST request? It looks like you do this to the `HomeView` or `DashboardView`, and a `TemplateView` normally does *not* handle POST requests.

Comment: The view.py is apps/view.py The html in`HomeView`, `DashboardView`, `TemplateView` has  <form method="POST">.

Comment: I followed the youtube tutorial and this is the code that I followed https://github.com/studygyaan/Django-CRM-Project/commit/3b3bc8556d663fad58ac7e893dabbc66597682d6#

Answer (score 0):

You should make a POST request to the `SignUpView`, not to the current view, the form thus looks like:

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
    <!-- … -->
</form>
```

Comment: Should I write `<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">` in 'common/register.html' or in 'common/home.html'?

Comment: @M.K.: in *both*, it is typically *not* a good idea *not* to specify the handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works out well when I write `<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">` both. But, I want  `common/dashboard.html` to be the next page. So I tired `<form action="{% url 'dashboard' %}" method="POST">` but, It didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: @M.K.: use `<form action="{% url 'register' %}?next={% url 'dashboard' %}"`.

Comment: @M.K. Your view should also log in the user, currently you are only *creating* a user...